# Why do i get error 138 when doing a find followed by a create?

Tags: progress-4gl

I have the following code block which when run, gives error 138 and the create is actually failing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
FIND PSESCDel EXCLUSIVE-LOCK
             WHERE PSESCDel.EmployeeCode    = PSESC.EmployeeCode
               AND PSESCDel.ServiceCoverRef = PSESC.ServiceCoverRef NO-ERROR.


        IF NOT AVAILABLE PSESCDel THEN
        DO:
            IF PSESC.EmployeeCode = "0358" THEN
                    MESSAGE "RM NOT AV" PSESC.ServiceCoverRef.

            CREATE PSESCDel.
            ASSIGN PSESCDel.EmployeeCode    = PSESC.EmployeeCode
                   PSESCDel.ServiceCoverRef = PSESC.ServiceCoverRef
                   PSESCDel.DeletedDate     = TODAY.

            IF PSESC.EmployeeCode = "0350" THEN
            DO:
                    MESSAGE "RM IT CAME TO CREATE".
                    IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR OR ERROR-STATUS:NUM-MESSAGES > 0 THEN DO:
                            MESSAGE "RM ERROR NUMBER" STRING(ERROR-STATUS:GET-NUMBER(1)).
                            MESSAGE "RM ERROR MESSAGE" ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1).
                    END.
            END.



        END.
```

Comment: This isn't a solution, but your transaction scoping is potentially problematic. The find exclusive will start a transaction block, that from the code snippet is pointless as you're not updating the record. You may well do that later, but it's still bad practise. Your top level find should be no-lock. If you want to update the record later, then find it on a named buffer, inside a strongly scoped transaction block. (do for buffer-name transaction). Your create should also be on a named buffer and in a strongly scoped transaction block. You don't want to have screen messages in a trans block.

Comment: Check for create triggers in that table. It might reference some record that is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of error 138 is: "The record you were looking for does not exist or cannot pass the selection given by your combination of WHERE, OF, and USING phrases." A record does not exist in your database that matches the EmployeeCode and ServiceCoverRef that you have in your FIND statement.

I'm guessing you are seeing this in your "RM ERROR NUMBER" message towards the bottom of your code snippet. The error that Progress produces is suppressed by the NO-ERROR phrase on your FIND statement. You might want to display those two values from the PSESC record and make sure they are what you expect them to be.